# Summing two columns in the same query from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have a 2015 and 2016 tables which have the same columns. I'm trying to display the totals from the separate years of one column.

```
SELECT t16.`Dep Name`, sum(t16.`number_courses`) AS `Total 16`, sum(t15.`number_courses`) 
AS `Total 15` FROM `table_16` t16, `table_15` t15
GROUP BY t16.`Dep Name`
```

This gives me wrong totals but when I do the totals separately, they work just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Okay, my main goal was to create a view but apparently according to [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html) subqueries aren't supported by views. Is there another way I can achieve the same result and create a view?

Comment: Please show us sample data.  What are the columns of each table, and show us some rows in the tables, along with your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially doing a `CROSS JOIN` which produces a cartesian product of the rows of both tables.

You can instead *first* aggregate and *then* join:

```
SELECT t16.`Dep Name`, `Total 16`, `Total 15`
FROM (
  SELECT `Dep Name`, 
         sum(`number_courses`) AS `Total 16`
  FROM `table_16` 
  GROUP BY `Dep Name`) t16
JOIN (
  SELECT `Dep Name`, 
         sum(`number_courses`) AS `Total 15`
  FROM `table_15` 
  GROUP BY `Dep Name`
) t15 ON t16.`Dep Name` = t15.`Dep Name`
```

Comment: Okay, my main goal was to create a view but apparently according to [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html) subqueries aren't supported by views. Is there another way I can achieve the same result and create a view?